# Scrapy writing XPath expression for unknown depth

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have an html file which is like:

```
<div id='author'> 
   <div>
      <div>
         ...

             <a> John Doe </a>
```

I do not know how many div's would be under the author div. It may have different depth for different pages.

So what would be the XPath expression for this kind of xml?

By the way, I tried:

```
//div[@id = "author"]/*/a/text()
```

but this only seems to work for grandchildren of the author div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double slash to find an `a` element anywhere inside the `div` element with `id="author"`:

```
//div[@id = "author"]//a/text()
```